# Postgres 9.3 64 Bit Windows 7 and 64 bit Postgres install - cleared password no longer connects

Tags: postgresql, windows

[image][image]Originally I allocated a password to the postgres database, but for some stupid reason the servers are usually setup with a blank password.

I then assigned it a blank password in PGAdmin III, and it accepted this.  However when I restarted the server it complained `fe_sendauth: no password supplied.

I have tried following the other posts, but the service won't start if I supply any of the supplied config_types.

I think this must be connected to it being a 64 bit install.

Before checking this site, my colleague suggested

```
host    all             all             samehost            trust
```

I put this in the `# IPv4 connections:` section but whilst the server starts it still repeats the same error message

It seems pretty stupid that it accepts a blank password before the .conf settings have been made because it seems that now I am at the point of no return

Comment: There is no such thing as a "server password" in Postgres. And Postgres doesn't need a password to start unless you  mis-configured the Windows service that runs Postgres.

Comment: When the install of Postgres ran, it asked for a password and I added one.  Then I found from my colleagues that it should have been left blank, so to make it match I removed the password.  It allowed me to do this, now I cannot log on.  Whether it is called a Server Password or not, the server/PG Admin III is asking me for a password, and neither the old one or an empty one allow me access to the system.